# How to display roles labels in Sonata Admin instead of role names in the form

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

[image]

I already have these roles in the Form Create and Edit of Sonata Admin extends from FOSUserBundle. But what I want is:

1. I don't want to display all of this roles just a few roles like below.

> - "ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_LIST"
> - "ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_PRODUCT_EDIT"
> - "ROLE_ADMIN"
> - "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"
> - "SONATA"

2. I don't want to display something like ROLE_BLA_BLA, just want to display like:

> - "Role Product List"
> - "Role Product Edit"
> - "Role Admin"
> - "Role Sonata"

I tried a month ago but it didn't work, I had no good solution. I am just learning Symfony2, so anybody who have ideas or have experience on this issue please help me.

Comment: How about this [`Sonata Admin Enhanced View For Security Roles`](https://github.com/dianuj89/Sonata-admin-user-friendly-view-for-security-roles)

Comment: Wow, it's working so good. Thank you for improving my English and give a nice solution for me. Thank you, thank you !!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sonata admin enhanced view for security roles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314827/sonata-admin-enhanced-view-for-security-roles)

Comment: Sorry, can I see your User and Group entity and also UserAdmin.php because in my form doesn't have group. I can not create a group.

Answer (score 1):

1) I think this can be configured in `app/config/config.yml`:

```
# app/config/config.yml
sonata_admin:
    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.acl
        # acl security information
        information:
            GUEST:    [VIEW, LIST]
            STAFF:    [EDIT, LIST, CREATE]
            EDITOR:   [OPERATOR, EXPORT]
            ADMIN:    [MASTER]
        # permissions not related to an object instance and also to be available when objects do not exist
        # the DELETE admin permission means the user is allowed to batch delete objects
        admin_permissions: [CREATE, LIST, DELETE, UNDELETE, EXPORT, OPERATOR, MASTER]
        # permission related to the objects
        object_permissions: [VIEW, EDIT, DELETE, UNDELETE, OPERATOR, MASTER, OWNER]
```

More info on: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#configuration

2) You can simply add the appropriate translations of the `ROLE_XXX` strings to your translation files.

Symfony2 form component has support for translating error messages, field labels and other strings.

Comment: I am trying to test it now :) .

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Now I done with Mr. @M Khalid Junaid suggestion, commended on my post.

Answer (score 1):

Try to work with your own roles. I mean that you have to create another attribute ( like profile ) in the user entity and use it instead of the role attribute of sonata admin :

0- In your security.yml

```
 role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    SONATA:
        - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT 
        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN
    ROLE_0: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
    ROLE_1:  [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
    ROLE_2: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
    ROLE_3: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
    ROLE_4: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
    ROLE_5: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
    ROLE_6: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
    ROLE_7: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
```

1- In your user entity :

```
<field name="profile"  type="smallint"   column="profile"   nullable="true" />
```

2- add it in your formMapper and remove the sonata role attribute

```
->add('profile', 'choice', array(
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'profile_label',
            'translation_domain' => 'SonataUserBundle',
            'mapped' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'choices' => array(
                '0' => 'Role 0',
                '1' => 'Role 1',
                '2' => 'Role 2',
                '3' => 'Role 3',
                '4' => 'Role 4',
                '5' => 'Role 5',
                '6' => 'Role 6',
                '7' => 'Role 7')
        ))
```

3- In your UserAdmin controller define your custom array of roles as mentioned in security.yml with the same order of roles in the formMapper

```
protected $roleMapArary = array('ROLE_Role0','ROLE_Role1', 'ROLE_Role2', 'ROLE_Role3', 'ROLE_Role4', 'ROLE_Role5', 'ROLE_Role6', 'ROLE_Role6');
```

4 - Then in the create action of userAdminController

```
 if ($this->getRestMethod() == 'POST')
 {

  $roleArray = $this->get('request')->request->get($this->admin->getUniqid())['profile'];
  $roles = array();
  foreach ($roleArray as $key => $role)
  {
    $roles[] = $this->roleMapArary[$role];
  }
  $object->setRealRoles($roles);
  $form->submit($this->get('request'));
// ....
}
```

5- Then in your edit action :

```
$requestRoles = array();
$roles = array();
 $id = $this->get('request')->get($this->admin->getIdParameter());
$object = $this->admin->getObject($id);

if (!$object)
{
  throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('unable to find the object with id : %s', $id));
}

if (false === $this->admin->isGranted('EDIT', $object))
{
  throw new AccessDeniedException();
}

$this->admin->setSubject($object);
$realRoles = $object->getRealRoles();
if (sizeof($realRoles) > 0)
{
  foreach ($realRoles as $key => $value)
  {
    $trouve = array_search($value, $this->roleMapArary);
    if (is_int($trouve))
    {
      $requestRoles[] = $trouve;
    }
  }
}
/** @var $form \Symfony\Component\Form\Form */
$form = $this->admin->getForm();
$form->setData($object);
$form->get('profile')->setData($requestRoles);
if ($this->getRestMethod() == 'POST')
{
  $roleArray = $this->get('request')->request->get($this->admin->getUniqid())['profile'];

  foreach ($roleArray as $key => $role)
  {
    $roles[] = $this->roleMapArary[$role];
  }
  $object->setRealRoles($roles);
  $form->submit($this->get('request'));
  $isFormValid = $form->isValid();
// ...
```

6- make sure that you add the getProfile and setProfile in your user entity:

```
  public function setProfile($profile) {
    $this->profile = $profile;

    return $this;
  }

 public function getProfile() {
    $profile = '';

    $roleMapArary = array('ROLE_Role0','ROLE_Role1', 'ROLE_Role2', 'ROLE_Role3', 'ROLE_Role4', 'ROLE_Role5', 'ROLE_Role6', 'ROLE_Role6');
    // your array as string (as  you want to show them == the same as formMapper)
    $profileMapArary = array(

    'Role 0 string',
    'Role 1 string ',
    'Role 2 string ',
    'Role 3 string ',
    'Role 4 string ',
    'Role 5 string ',
    'Role 6 string ',
    'Role 7 string ',);
   $roleArray = $this->getRealRoles();

   if (sizeof($roleArray) > 0)
   {
     foreach ($roleArray as $key => $value)
     {
       $trouve = array_search($value, $roleMapArary);
       if (is_int($trouve))
       {
         $profile = $profileMapArary[$trouve]. ' - '.$profile;        

       }
     }
     $profile = substr($profile, 0, -2);
   }
   return $profile;
 }
```

Comment: should I create userAdminController because now It doesn't have.

Comment: Yes you should. Then override create and edit actions.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Now I done with Mr. @M Khalid Junaid suggestion, commended on my post.