# Sonata admin enhanced view for security roles

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle, sonata

In sonata admin the roles are based on admin services name with CRUD export and master permissions but the way it looks not so user friendly to create groups for others user or assign specific permissions to a user considering an example for sonata admin post module the service for admin is named as `sonata.news.admin.post` and for that service generated roles will look like

```
ROLE_SONATA_NEWS_ADMIN_POST_EDIT
ROLE_SONATA_NEWS_ADMIN_POST_LIST
ROLE_SONATA_NEWS_ADMIN_POST_CREATE
ROLE_SONATA_NEWS_ADMIN_POST_VIEW
ROLE_SONATA_NEWS_ADMIN_POST_DELETE
ROLE_SONATA_NEWS_ADMIN_POST_EXPORT
ROLE_SONATA_NEWS_ADMIN_POST_OPERATOR
ROLE_SONATA_NEWS_ADMIN_POST_MASTER
```

For a normal user its difficult to read/assign roles is there a better way for representation of generated roles ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>**Adding my own answer**</sup>

In Sonata admin if you wish to change display security roles as a user friendly view you have to override below sonata's services

- sonata.user.editable_role_builder
- sonata.user.form.type.security_roles

And definitions will look like as below

```
    <services>
        <service id="sonata.user.editable_role_builder" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Security\EditableRolesBuilder">
            <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
            <argument type="service" id="sonata.admin.pool" />
            <argument>%security.role_hierarchy.roles%</argument>
        </service>
        <service id="sonata.user.form.type.security_roles" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\SecurityRolesType">
            <tag name="form.type" alias="sonata_security_roles" />
            <argument type="service" id="sonata.user.editable_role_builder" />
        </service>

    </services>
```

---

And define your classes in these services for, Demo code i have used `Acme\DemoBundle`

Now `SecurityRolesType` class is dependendant of Sonata's `EditableRolesBuilder` you have to make it dependent of your own `EditableRolesBuilder` Class so in same way override dependency of sonata's `RestoreRolesTransformer` to your class

I have transformed all roles to an array of module wise roles in `SecurityRolesType.php` and passed it to view all customization you can view in this file

Also override the twig template for roles you can overrride it by coping `form_admin_fields.html.twig` from `vendor\sonata-project\user-bundle\Resources\views` and adding `app\Resources\SonataUserBundle\views\Form` path it will override parent twig file,In twig file i have tried to use accordion control bootstrap to display roles module wise and with appropriate permissions

---

> Note: This code will only display permissions
>   [Create,Edit,View,List,Export,Delete,Master] it will not handle custom
>   permission

Last step import your service file in main configuration file that is `config.yml`

```
    imports:
        - { resource: parameters.yml }
        - { resource: security.yml }
        - { resource: @AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/admin.xml }
```

---

For full code demo you can find it in below repository

[`Sonata Admin Enhanced View For Security Roles`](https://github.com/dianuj89/Sonata-admin-user-friendly-view-for-security-roles)

### Module Permissions Preview

[image]